# Customized Bootstrap Carousel - only show set number of DIVs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have implemented a bootstrap carousel which looks like this on loading:

[image]

The code is as follows:

html:

```
    <div class="container text-center my-3">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-wrap="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">

                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                2
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
... carousel-item divs repeat to 18 ...
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                18
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function () {
    var minPerSlide = 12;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
        display: block;
    }

        .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
            display: block;
        }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* display 12 */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        transform: translateX(8.333%);
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        transform: translateX(-8.333%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

I don't want to the carousel to repeat when I get to the end (clicking the right arrow 6 times):

[image]

However it seems I can continue clicking the right arrow until the 18 is the first div in the row:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to stop the right button from carrying out a move when the last (18) div first appears on screen (i.e. the second screenshot above).

Any help is greatly appreciated or if anything isn't clear please let me know.

Comment: disable the first arrow once you reach max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find the event that fires 'after' a slide completes and this is where I needed to handle the changes. Also, making use of the current Active attribute that gets auto-assigned to the current WeatherElement. Code working now looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-wrap="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner carousel-weather w-100" role="listbox">

                <div id="weatherCard_0" class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ... repeat till 18

                <div id="weatherCard_18" class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            18
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <a id="leftWeatherButton" class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a id="rightWeatherButton" class="carousel-control carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I have removed the `onClick()` events from the buttons.

Jaascript:

```
$('#recipeCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {

    var $this = $(this);

   $this.children('.carousel-control').show();

    var weatherElements = $('.carousel-weather')[0].children;
    var elementsLength = weatherElements.length - 1;
    var first = weatherElements[0];
    var lastCount;

    if (elementsLength <= 11) {
        lastCount = 0
    }
    else {
        lastCount = elementsLength - 11;
    }

    var last = weatherElements[lastCount];

    if ($(last).hasClass('active')) {
        $this.children('.carousel-control-next').hide();
    } else if ($(first).hasClass('active')) {
        $this.children('.carousel-control-prev').hide();
    }

});

function ManageWeatherButtons() {

    $("#leftWeatherButton").hide();
    $("#rightWeatherButton").hide();

    debugger;
    if (weatherCards.length > 12) {
        $("#rightWeatherButton").show();
    }
}
```

Which replaces all of the javascript from the initial code example.

This seems to work a lot better and will behave no matter how much you click the buttons.